# Cron job using "whenever" ruby gem is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

On my local I am generating sitemaps with the help of `sitemap_generator` gem. I have set up everything and now when I run `rake sitemap:generate` it is generating sitemap. Now I am trying to schedule this process using `whenever` gem. My schedule.rb is as follows:

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.minutes do
    rake "sitemap:refresh"
end
```

I keep my rails server running but nothing seems to happen after 1 minute. I might be missing something here. Before I push it on production server I wanted to check it. Can someone please tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run `crontab -l` and check if cronjob is scheduled.

Comment: I got `no crontab for mypc`

Comment: try `whenever --update-crontab` and then check crontab as per @DIGITALSQUAD comment.

Comment: It got updated. But still no cron job after 1 minute.

Comment: This is phrased as a comment, but entered as an answer. Either change the wording so it's a statement/answer, or delete it and ask a question in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your schedule.rb to cron syntax.
Try

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

And then check crontab.

```
crontab -l
```

[Whenever command](https://github.com/javan/whenever#the-whenever-command)

Comment: Ok after I did `whenever --update-crontab` I got `crontab updated`. Then I restarted my rails server and waited for 1-2 minutes nothing happened.

Comment: You don't need to restart rails server because it is nothing to do with whenever process directory.
Are you sure to run cron process ?
Try `pgrep cron` and you got a process number.

Comment: `pggrep` gave `629`